# Node Google App Engine is not working error : Server Error Please try again in 30 seconds

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, yaml, google-cloud-platform, google-appengine-node

My node app that's on google app engine was working fine and then suddenly after another deployment, it started bringing this error:

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your
>   request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

I check the log there is no error or any problem notification.

Here is my app.yaml content:

```
# [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

# [START env]
env_variables:
  MYSQL_USER: adminpard
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
  # e.g. my-awesome-project:us-central1:my-cloud-sql-instance
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: kock-130024:us-east1:osdb 
 # [END env]

# [START cloudsql_settings]
beta_settings:
  # The connection name of your instance, available by using
  # 'gcloud beta sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]' or from
  # the Instance details page in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
  cloud_sql_instances: kock-130024:us-east1:osdb 
# [END cloudsql_settings]
# [END app_yaml]
```

Here is also my .dockerignore file:

```
.git 
projects.sln 
.vs 
myproject.njsproj 
.gitignore 
node_module 
skills
npm-debug.log
```

I am little bit confused I need some guidance to understand where the problem is or how to solve it.